# Why I cannot import this module in Python with PTVS?

Tags: python, ptvs

I am using VS2013 with PTVS.

I can see the module datasets with dir():

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'datasets', 'pprint']
```

And *datasets* is a module:

```
>>> type(datasets)
<type 'module'>
```

But I cannot import the *datasets* module:

```
>>> import datasets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named datasets

>>> from datasets import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named datasets
```

I did this because I don't want to save some typing of "datasets". Why this error?

Comment: What is `datasets.__name__`?

Answer (score 0):

`dir()` shows you the local variables. What this output means is that 1) you have a global variable named `datasets`, and 2) it references a module. This would normally indicate that someone has imported it already in your scope. But `import` itself does not operate on variables, it operates on modules directly.

If I had to guess, the module is probably not actually named `datasets`, it's just that someone did `from .. import` or `import .. as`. You need to find out what the actual name of the module is.